# matplotlib barh for scheduled hours vs actual hours worked

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, gantt-chart

I am trying to build a horizontal bar chart for employees showing their scheduled hours worked vs. their actual hours worked for a given day.

I have tried the following code but as you can see in the 'Plot' image below, it is concatenating the actual hours worked (blue) to the ends of the scheduled hours (green). Also the time's on the x axis are not very telling.

What I am after is to have two bars for each employee, a green bar showing the scheduled hours at the top and a blue bar for the actual hours worked underneath, something like a gantt chart almost. Can anybody help me understand where I am going wrong in my code?

```
#import stack
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

#dummy df
df = pd.DataFrame([['Bob', '2018-09-14 9:00:00', '2018-09-14 18:00:00', 'actual']
                   , ['Bob', '2018-09-14 9:15:00', '2018-09-14 18:30:00', 'scheduled']
                   , ['Kim', '2018-09-14 9:00:00', '2018-09-14 18:00:00', 'actual']
                   , ['Kim', '2018-09-14 8:45:00', '2018-09-14 17:30:00', 'scheduled']]
                   , columns=['name','start','finish', 'type'])

#convert timestamp columns to datetime
df[['start', 'finish']] = df[['start', 'finish']].apply(pd.to_datetime)

#scheduled time period
scheduledStart = mdates.date2num(df['start'][(df['type'] == 'scheduled')].dt.to_pydatetime())
scheduledEnd =  mdates.date2num(df['finish'][(df['type'] == 'scheduled')].dt.to_pydatetime())
scheduledWidth = scheduledEnd - scheduledStart

#actual time period
actualStart = mdates.date2num(df['start'][(df['type'] == 'actual')].dt.to_pydatetime())
actualEnd =  mdates.date2num(df['finish'][(df['type'] == 'actual')].dt.to_pydatetime())
actualWidth = actualEnd - actualStart

#y axis values
yval = df['name'].unique()

#generate plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.barh(yval, width = actualWidth, left = actualStart, color = 'blue', height = 0.3, label = 'actual')
ax.barh(yval, width = scheduledWidth, left = scheduledStart, color = 'green', height = 0.3, label = 'scheduled')

#format x axis to time of day
xfmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%m')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)

# autorotate the dates
fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

[image: figure]

Comment: I think the problem is the yval. Try different values such as `[0, 1]` for the first and `[0.3, 1.3]` for the second `ax.barh` (so they do not overlap). And change yticks: `plt.yticks([0.15, 1.15], yval)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try different values such as `[0, 1]` for the first and `[0.3, 1.3]` for the second `ax.barh` (so they do not overlap). We are simply shifting the `height` value.

```
ax.barh([0, 1], width = actualWidth, left = actualStart, color = 'blue', height = 0.3, label = 'actual')
ax.barh([0.3, 1.3], width = scheduledWidth, left = scheduledStart, color = 'green', height = 0.3, label = 'scheduled')
```

And change `yticks` (choosing the center between the two bars):

```
plt.yticks([0.15, 1.15], yval)
```

finally to fix the `xtick`:

```
fig.autofmt_xdate(ha='center')
```

[image: example_figure]